# (La) confiance dans le mystère qui nous fait exister

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

*Journal d'un amour perdu* d'Éric-Emmanuel Schmitt :

> Dans mes convictions, rien ne m'enseigne sur l'au-delà. Simplement, je
> cultive la confiance. **Confiance** dans le mystère qui nous fait exister.
> **Confiance** dans la vie. **Confiance** dans la mort.

Pourquoi l'auteur a-t-il omis l'article dans ces phrases ? Est-ce que cette omission renforce le sens du mot "confiance" ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas ***La** confiance*. mais ***J'ai** confiance* … et il est mal séant de mettre son ego en avant, c'est donc une tournure élégante pour reprendre le mot clef d'une pensée.

Comment: @Personne Merci !

Answer (score 4):

L'ellipse de l'article donne au mot ***confiance*** un caractère plus générique et universel, plus de poids.

Cette emphase renforce le double effet de style produit par la combinaison d'une reprise de la fin d'une phrase par le début de la suivante (*...la confiance. Confiance...* : [anadiplose](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anadiplose)) suivie d'une succession de phrases débutant par le même mot (*Confiance... Confiance... Confiance...* : [anaphore](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphore_(rh%C3%A9torique))).

Answer (score 2):

À mon avis aucun renforcement du mot « confiance » n'est obtenu au moyen de l'omission de l'article, ni même aucun effet particulier, sauf celui de rendre le style légèrement plus lapidaire. La lecture du texte modifié ne semble pas apporter de connotation particulière.